# Run script after Node.js killed

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I'am using Node.js API to start a long living script using `spawn module`. My problem is that, when my Node.js API is stopped the started script also killed. Is there any solution to start a script via Node.js not on the Node.js thread?

Comment: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: I think its [Duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412711/how-to-auto-restart-node-script-or-init-d-service-starting-that-node-after-c) question.